# isNumberKey() not working

Tags: javascript, html, keyevent

A long time ago if found some code (on this site) that stopped the user from entering Letters into a text box, and it worked. Since finding this code I have changed it and added and now it doesn't work. This is what code I have:

```
var count = 1

function isNumberKey(event) {
var keyCode = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

if (event.keyCode === 8 // backspace
|| event.keyCode === 46 // delete
|| event.keyCode === 13 // enter key
|| event.keyCode === 9 // tab
|| event.keyCode === 116 // F5 (refresh)
|| event.keyCode === 112 // F1
|| event.keyCode === 113 //F2
|| event.keyCode === 114 //F3
|| event.keyCode === 115 //F4
|| event.keyCode === 117 //F6
|| event.keyCode === 118 //F7
|| event.keyCode === 119 //F8
|| event.keyCode === 120 //F9
|| event.keyCode === 121 //F10
|| event.keyCode === 122 //F11
|| event.keyCode === 123 //F12
) {
return true;
}
else if ( key < 48 || key > 57) {
if (count < 6) {
count++; //adds one to count
}
else {
alert("Please Only Enter Numerical Values");
count = 1;
}
return false;
}
else return true;
}
```

I'm not claiming I made/wrote this code but can anyone see any problems with the code?

Comment: when you say doesn't work what error / behaviour are you getting?

Comment: it still allows the user to enter letters

Comment: For some reason it isn't calling the function isNumberkey() when a button is pressed!

Comment: You have already assigned event.keyCode to keyCode variable at the top. So better to use it in rest of your method for cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. It was not working because you use `key < 48 || key > 57` instead `event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57`

```
var count = 1

function isNumberKey(event) {
    var keyCode = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (event.keyCode === 8 // backspace
        || event.keyCode === 46 // delete
        || event.keyCode === 13 // enter key
        || event.keyCode === 9 // tab
        || event.keyCode === 116 // F5 (refresh)
        || event.keyCode === 112 // F1
        || event.keyCode === 113 //F2
        || event.keyCode === 114 //F3
        || event.keyCode === 115 //F4
        || event.keyCode === 117 //F6
        || event.keyCode === 118 //F7
        || event.keyCode === 119 //F8
        || event.keyCode === 120 //F9
        || event.keyCode === 121 //F10
        || event.keyCode === 122 //F11
        || event.keyCode === 123 //F12
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
        if (count < 6) {
            count++; //adds one to count
        }
        else {
            alert("Please Only Enter Numerical Values");
            count = 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that must be the problem, for some reason I'm getting lots of System Reference Errors (using Fire Bug) and that must be stoping the code form working

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
textBox.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (/\d/.test(charStr)) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: `var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;` can be reduced further down to `var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;`

Answer (score 0):

This came up when I was asking, so it might be worth adding here that `keyCode` and `charCode` is deprecated, as at this time, so the accepted answer might not be the best.

A better way of adding the check or implementing the isNumberKey function could be:

```
const isNumberKey = (event: KeyboardEvent) => 
   ((event.key.length > 1) || event.key.match(/^\d|-$/))
```

This way, we check allow special keys do their function, while making sure only numbers are allowed when single character keys are pressed.